# How to send a price parameter to opencart

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

At the moment my opencart product is added to the cart using the button and function script below. I'm able to send the product_id, & quantity to the shopping cart and that works fine.

How do I also adjust the price? I'm a little confused on this, because the price can change. I always want to add product_id=40 to the cart, but want to change the price according to other params that will be sent. I tried adding price like this: `addToCart(product_id, quantity, price)` and then `<a onclick="addToCart('40','1', 100);" class="button"> but that only seemed to increase the quantity and not the price.`

the button that runs the `addToCart` function when clicked:

```
 <a onclick="addToCart('40','1');" class="button">
<button style="background:#990000;color:#fff">Order Now</button></a>
```

my script:

```
<script>
function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
        console.log('Testing console values');
        console.log(window.result); 
        console.log(window.quantity);
        console.log(window.product);    
        console.log(window.selectedStringName); 
        console.log(window.selectedString); 
        console.log(window.product_name);   

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://****.com/purchase/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {

                window.location='http://***.com/purchase/index.php?route=checkout/cart'; 

                // $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');
                //              
                //              $('.success').fadeIn('slow');
                //              
                //              $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
                //              
                //              $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

thanks for any help with this.

Comment: how do you want your price to change .. on what parameters ? your `addToCart` function takes only two argument then why are you expecting it to do something when you pass third argument `price`? if you just want to send a arbitrary price you should add some handling to server also to verify price.. i am sorry but your question is poorly explained

Comment: thanks. I changed the function so that it took:         data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity + '&price=' + price, and then added <a onclick="addToCart('40','1', 100);" class="button"> but that didn't work. the price is calculated elsewhere. here though I just added it as '100' as the 3rd parameter in the <a onclick="addToCart('40','1', 100);" class="button"> code

Comment: you still didn't answered my question.... on what parameters you want your price to change or you just want to send some arbitrary price to cart ?

Comment: I want the price to be calculated on a document word count that the customer can order. I have already calculated it and just need to pass that calculated price to the ocart shopping cart. not sure if it's the correct way to do it, but I've made a generic product (product_id = 40) and would like to have the customer calculate the price (based on the amount of words in a document they will be ordering) an then pass that to the cart. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Sending the price over from JavaScript is completely wrong!

Consider this situation: You are selling iMacs and MacBooks. Let's say the basic price for one iMac is $1.200 but according to some settings You want the price to change to $1.699. So You would have this in Your HTML:

```
<a onclick="addToCart(14, 1, 1699);">Buy this iMac</a>
```

Now somebody like me (who is always looking also into the code) will notice this - it is our duty to try to open our web developer tool and to manipulate the price, so we will change the HTML to this:

```
<a onclick="addToCart(14, 1, 1);">Buy this iMac</a>
```

If it would work how You suggest I will be able to buy a $1.699 iMac for the price of $1 and according to the laws You have to ship it...

So what You actually should need is to calculate the price accordingly **but in the backend** so that nobody can manipulate the final price of the product...